# NoSuchMethodException when loading SurfaceView through XML

Tags: android

At the moment I have a class that extends Activity, with an inner class ("GameView") extending SurfaceView (and implementing Runnable)

```
public class GameSurface extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
```

and

```
public  class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
```

Everything works fine, but I decided to add some buttons to the View and instead of drawing the bitmaps I would rather make use of a FrameLayout and load the buttons as ImageButtons on top of the Canvas.

So I tried to load the GameView through XML  as followed:

game_layout.xml

```
<view
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.appname.game.GameSurface$GameView" >
</view>
```

So now I created a new class extending Activity and did

```
            setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);
```

Not working though. I get a few errors/exceptions

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.appname.game.GameSurface$GameView
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

So I found some questions asked here on StackOverflow on the NoSuchMethodException and saw that this last error was related to missing or inaccesible constructors. **The constructors are all there**, including the one that is mentioned in the error.

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);

        //bunch of code
}
```

So I **assume** that the constructor is inaccessible and other answers mentioned that I should make the constructor static. The problem is that the code is now making static references to non-static methods and fields, which is not possible and resulted in a lot of errors.

What is the best thing I can do about this without making too much changes?
If more info is required to get a clearer view I am more than happy to provide it. Thanks

UPDATE:
Stack trace
http://pastebin.com/ZtZQUv7B

Comment: Is it a typo that the constructor `OurView` is "OurView" not "GameView"? Can you post more code/stack trace?

Comment: Why is `GameView` an inner class of your `Activity`? I would recommend making it its own class, and use the fully-qualified classname instead of the view tag (e.g. `<com.appname.game.GameView android:layout_width...`)

Comment: Yes that was a typo, sorry about that. See Update for the stack trace of the exception

Comment: @kcoppock I would not mind doing that at all, I even think it will look cleaner. I reference quite some methods and fields in the View and did not manage to get this to work.

Comment: You should restructure your View's design -- add some properties and callback interfaces. Your View should have no reason to directly reference your Activity's state, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner class needs to be static. There is no way I can see around it. You will need to refactor enough using interfaces as necessary. `class="com.appname.game.GameSurface$GameView"` will search and create a class defined by the value of the attribute without care or knowledge   of instantiated classes.